# Postgresql how to do subselect in select base on value in main select

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to select 5 nearest places base on location found in main select.
So far I done this.

```
SELECT p.*, 
                ST_AsGeoJSON(p.coordinate) as coordiantes,
                (
                    SELECT json_agg(op.id) AS otherplaces
                    FROM places op 
                    GROUP BY op.coordinate, op.id
                    ORDER BY coordinate <-> st_geogfromwkb(p.coordinate) 
                    LIMIT 5
                ) AS other
                FROM places p
                WHERE id = 1
```

As you see I would like to get value call **other** where will be array of (id,name) subselect result.

But now I got an error. "op.coordiante" must be present in **group by**. When I added that expression then I recive other error. "More then single row return in subselect".

So how to do it correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, 
                ST_AsGeoJSON(p.coordinate) as coordiantes,
                (
                    SELECT json_agg(foo.id) AS otherplaces
                    FROM
                      (
                        SELECT op.id
                        FROM places op 
                        ORDER BY coordinate <-> st_geogfromwkb(p.coordinate) 
                        LIMIT 5
                      ) AS foo
                ) AS other
                FROM places p
                WHERE id = 1
```